# Which kind of list is the one and how to manipulate it?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am using OpenCV to detect BRISK keypoints this way:

```
img = cv2.imread(image_path)
gray= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kp, descriptors = cv2.BRISK_create().detectAndCompute(gray,None)
```

kp is a list, however, it is also a kind of struct. It has parameters or "sublists" such as kp.pt values, kp. response values and so on. I am a little rookie in Python so I would like to know the following.

1-Is there a specific name for this list? it does not seem to be the list I am used to using in Python. How to get more information about this kind of list?

2- How can I know what are the other parameters (or "sublists") of kp? can I print them in Python?

3- How can I save in a variable all elements of, for example, kp.response? I can only index individual elements like this kp[1].response

4-How can I sort kp.response values, getting the indices of the N highest kp.response values?

Comment: One question at a time please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- `type(kp)` This gets the class that the object is an instance of.

2- `dir(kp)` This should list the attributes of the object. For certain very dynamic types that generate their attributes on the fly in response to access attempts, this might not work. (But it still might, since `dir` can also be generated dynamically.)

In that case, if you can find the `__getattr__` method in the source code of the class, it might give you a clue where those dynamic attributes are actually stored.

3- `[e.response for e in kp]` probably. Usually if it's indexible like that it's also iterable.

4- `print([i for _, i in sorted((e.response, i) for i, e in enumerate(kp))[-N:]])` haven't tested this.

Also try `help(kp)`, it might explain how to use it better. Use `help` on anything you don't understand. It might have a docstring.

> Now I just need to figure out how to use the resulting list as kp indexes

Maybe something like `[kp[i] for i in indexes]`?

Comment: 1- Ok, thanks. 2- the attributes of the object show functions like 'append', 'count', 'extend', which are more list attributes than the variable attributes (for example, there are kp.pt, kp.response, what are the others?) 3- Ok, thank you 4- Thanks.

Comment: It works! Now I just need to figure out how to use the resulting list as kp indices

Comment: x=[i for _, i in sorted((e.response, i) for i, e in enumerate(kp))[-1000:]] and show=[kp[i] for i in x]. Thank you so much, I learned a lot from you!